# How Do You Initialize a Hash Table to Store in a File in C

Tags: c, file, initialization, hashtable

I am trying to implement a  fixed-size hash table in C using linear probing for collision resolution. This hash table will be stored in a file for later (and quick) retrieval via the hash values that are generated. I have most of the kinks taken care of, but I seem to be stuck in initializing the table that I will be using. I thought using an array of the type of struct I am registering and then initializing all the values to either NULL or blank "" was the way to go, but now I am not so sure.

I am also unsure as to how the retrieval process would work. I haven't found any useful resources online that delineate this for the C language. When retrieving information for a specific index, do I need to load the whole hash table in memory (this seems impractical) or is there a way to load in the specific index contents (maybe using lseek to locate the right file location)?

I am including only the code associated with the hash table initialization, but please let me know if you need more. Thanks in advance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define HSZ 10

struct client{
char last_name[80];
char maiden_name[80];
char name[80];
}client;

void init_array(){

int fd, i;
int bucket_no = 0;
struct client buff;

   if ((fd = open("output", O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0777))<0){
        perror("Inside init function: ");
        printf("There was a problem initializing the hash table!");
   }
     for (i = 0; i<HSZ; i++){

            strcpy(buff.name,"_");
            strcpy(buff.last_name,"_");
            strcpy(buff.maiden_name,"_");

            lseek(fd, sizeof client * bucket_no, SEEK_SET);
            write(fd, &buff, sizeof client);

            bucket_no++;
        }
close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `mmap()` is probably the simplest approach, as long as each bucket is a fixed size like in your example, it's easy to calculate an offset to seek to in the file before reading a given one - or do both steps in one using [`pread()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html).

Something like

```
int bucket_number = 4; // 0 based like an array
struct client bucket;
lseek(hash_fd, sizeof bucket * bucket_number, SEEK_SET);
read(hash_fd, &bucket, sizeof bucket);
```

or

```
pread(hash_fd, &bucket, sizeof bucket, sizeof bucket * bucket_number);
```

And for writing buckets to the file, use `write()` or `pwrite()` with the same sort of math for individual ones - or write an entire array's worth at once when creating the file.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution definitely worked for me for finessing the write and read methods for this. I just have one last question. Every time I initialize my hash table  using just "_" I get a bunch of  garbage in between the "_" in the file. Is this considered normal? Is there any way to only keep what I am putting in for the variables? I updated the code to be more clear...

Comment: @LuisAlberto You'e only initializing the first two elements of each array in the struct. The rest is filled with random garbage bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mmap`. It basically allows you to access the file like it was an array.

```
struct stat s = stat(filename, &s);
size_t size = s.st_size;
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
struct client *map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, fd, 0);
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely be of use to me in the future. For this particular exercise, though, I am prohibited from using any pre-defined structures.